# If $F$ is convex, then so is $x \mapsto \inf_{y\in Y} F(x, y)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and $f:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$. Then its *domain* is defined as $D(f) := \{x\in E : f(x) \neq \pm\infty\}$. Let $X,Y$ be vector spaces and $X \times Y$ their [direct product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Direct_Product_of_Vector_Spaces/Finite_Case) which is a vector space with induced component-wise operation.

I'm trying to prove below result, i.e.,

> **Theorem** Let $F:X \times Y \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ and $f:X \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$ such that $f(x) := \inf_{y\in Y}F(x, y)$. If $F$ is convex, then so is $f$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**My attempt** Let $x_1, x_2 \in D(f)$ and $t \in (0, 1)$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. There are $y_1, y_2 \in Y$ such that $F(x_1, y_1) < f(x_1) + \varepsilon$ and $F(x_2, y_2) < f(x_2) + \varepsilon$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2) &\le F(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2, ty_1 + (1-t)y_2) \\
&\overset{(\star)}{\le} t F(x_1, y_1)+(1-t) F(x_2, y_2) \\
&\le t(f(x_1) + \varepsilon) + (1-t)(f(x_2) + \varepsilon) \\
&= tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2) +\varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$

Here $(\star)$ is due to the convexity of $F$. We take the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ and get
$$
f(tx_1 + (1-t)x_2)  \le  tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2).
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: This seems perfect to me.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you so much for your verification!